# How to inherit from two content types

Tags: sharepoint-online, column

How could i inherit from two contentypes?
Doing like this dont work?

```
   <ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4" Name="Welcomepage" Group="My Content Types" Description="Welcome page" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
<ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D010021935596B4CE427A892D41E2BBED1797" Name="My own content type" Group="My Content Types" Description="Welcome page" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">

<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef ID="{e854ecfc-6f7e-47e5-8b86-6f7cac951fca}"  Required="FALSE" Name="PageContent1" />
  <FieldRef ID="{ebc7bfe0-c3fd-4967-8127-8a30f2894d19}"  Required="FALSE" Name="PageContent2" />
  <FieldRef ID="{e3d9a193-a06e-4e61-9f57-67048ac9be0c}"  Required="FALSE" Name="PageContent3" />
</FieldRefs>


 </ContentType>
 </ContentType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will definitely not work. You are talking about nesting content types, which is not possible in SharePoint. Refer to this MSDN article on Content Type IDs and Inheritance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543822%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Content types are inherited by using the ID of parent content type and adding another ID at the end:

[image]

More info on Content Type hierarchy here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms452896%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can only inherit from one parent, so if you want to inherit both ContentTypeA and ContentTypeB into ContentTypeC, you need to inherit ContentTypeB from ContentTypeA and ContentTypeC from ContentTypeB.